# OSX not respecting PATH when trying to install homebrew php

Tags: php, bash, macos, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I have installed homebrew-php php72 on OSX high sierra. Strangely when I run php I still get the pre-installed php 7.1 - even more strangely when I run `which php` it tells me that it will use the homebrew version from `/usr/local/bin` not the pre-installed version in `/usr/bin`. I dont have an aliases set up.

Some shell output:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php

$ php --version
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

$ /usr/local/bin/php --version
PHP 7.2.3 (cli) (built: Mar  8 2018 10:30:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

$ /usr/bin/php --version
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

$ alias | grep php # There are no aliases
$

$ type -a php
php is /usr/local/bin/php
php is /usr/bin/php
```

I cant think of any reason this could happen any ideas?

Thanks
NFV

Comment: What does your .bash_profile look like for where it sets the PATH?

Comment: Show output of `type -a php`

Comment: I dont have a `.bash_profile` on this machine, but do have a `.profile` - it does not touch the PATH though

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk added, thanks

Comment: Try this: `hash -r`

Comment: Try adding the path adjustment to your .profile: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` then do `source ~/.profile` after saving from vim. What you describe though is really ODD ... `which php` shows the right path!

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk brilliant `hash -r` fixed it - never had to use that command before! Thanks

Comment: OK, I changed into an answer then.

Comment: I'll blame OSX's new "lets cache everything and cause mayhem" direction lately for this one =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the commands `hash -r` fixed the issue. From `help hash`:

```
  -r                forget all remembered locations
```

And just for the record: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then/85250)